# Moment 2.15 doesn't seem to handle offset tokens in format strings

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

Moment doesn't seem to like the format string here. without the format string it parses it implicitly but I want to enforce the format. The below call returns `invalid date`.

```
moment('2016-09-09T15:07:16+00:00', 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ').local().format('D MMM YYYY');
```

Moment -v 2.15.0

Based on [the docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) I thought this would be all good...

Comment: you're input string is in a format that moment will just read: `moment('2016-09-09T15:07:16+00:00').local().format('D MMM YYYY');` will work.  If you do want to use the format string for some reason
`moment('2016-09-09T15:07:16+00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]').local().format('D MMM YYYY');`

you can play with the working code [here](https://runkit.com/arthur/582a3894f5baa400148ab8a2)

Comment: You are using wrong format, you should use` 'YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ssZ'`, moment's `YYYY` (year) and `DD` (day) tokens are **uppercase**

Comment: You can also just use [`moment.ISO_8601`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/special-formats/) if you don't feel like typing that much :).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan does this give me a `Z` or a `+00:00` on the end though?

Comment: Please don't be discouraged from providing the format to the parser. It's a really good idea to do so, even if redundant in some cases.